# How to open new web page with jquery colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I want to use jQuery colorbox to open web pages in my web site,
but it doesn't open in a dialog, it opens like an ordinary link...
I've searched for demos but I didn't find any working one.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="usersGrid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a class="user_details" href="UserDetails.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Id")%>">View details</a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/colorbox.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".user_details").colorbox({ iframe: true, innerWidth: 425, innerHeight: 344 });
    });
</script>
```

When I'm clicking the link, it just redirecting me to the given url, and I want it to open up in the colorbox dialog box...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your function inside the $(document).ready() event instead of invoking it immediately. This makes sure the DOM is loaded when you create the colorbox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".user_details").colorbox({ iframe: true, innerWidth: 425, innerHeight: 344 });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/